# How do you dynamically extract the middle name from an excel cell?

Tags: excel-formula

Extract the Middle Name from the Names given

consider cell A1 consist of data with trailing and leading spaces : 
          Pink Floyd     Laptop

Can someone help me out with a dynamic extraction of the middle name ?

Comment: What is middle name? The second of three words separated with spaces? Can there be more that three words?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)+1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)+1)-FIND(" ",A1,1)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this and it was working for me ;

=MID(TRIM(D8),FIND(" ",TRIM(D8),1)+1,FIND(" ",TRIM(D8),FIND(" ",TRIM(D8),1)+1)-FIND(" ",TRIM(D8),1))

for cell D8.

There were a number of leading and trailing spaces , so i had to use the TRIM() function.

Answer (score 0):

there is lot of time you using trim function it can be easily done with only one trim function. or using -1.

```
=MID(D8,FIND(" ",D8,1)+1,FIND(" ",D8,FIND(" ",D8,1)+1)-FIND(" ",1)-1)
```

Try this, it works for me.